# Have child item fill parent using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a navigation where I would like to have the child elements (in this case: a tags) fill the height of the flex parent (ul). Is it possible to not use padding and solely rely on flexbox here? Any help would be appreciated here. As you can see in the codepen, the black from the a tags does not fill the area. My eventual plan is to add a border at the top when the a tag is hovered. This is why I need to fill the area. I just want to use flexbox instead of padding if that is possible.

This is what I have so far:

```
<div class="nav">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

```
body,
html { background:skyblue; padding:0; margin:0; }
.nav {
    background-color:salmon;
    height:40px;
    ul          { display:flex; align-items:center; height:100%; }
    ul > li     { list-style:none; background:black; flex:1; }
    ul > li > a {  }
}
```

https://codepen.io/Jesders88/pen/GvQgzX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<a>` tags are indeed taking up the full height of their parent `<li>` elements -- You simply forgot to state that the `<li>` elements should take up `100%` of the height of the `<ul>` element.

Adding `height: 100%` to `.nav ul > li` causes the `<a>` tags to take up the full height of the `<ul>`, as in seen in this CodePen I've created **[here](https://codepen.io/Obsidian-Age/pen/EvQaqm)**.

Note that simply adding `height: 100%` causes the `<a>` tags to be displayed flush up against the top of the navbar. If you want to both vertically and horizontally center the `<a>` tags in the expanded navbar, you can do this by also making the `<li>` elements flexbox themselves, and utilising **[`align-items`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items)** and **[`justify-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content)**:

```
.nav ul > li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

I've created a secondary CodePen showcasing this **[here](https://codepen.io/Obsidian-Age/pen/QMQbWW)**.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I overthought that. It all makes sense now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using flexbox, centering is very easy and you can get rid of percentage heights. In addition, your HTML structure can be simplified.

```css
body,
html {
  background: skyblue;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  background-color: salmon;
  height: 40px;
}

a {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#">Link</a>
  <a href="#">Link</a>
  <a href="#">Link</a>
  <a href="#">Link</a>
  <a href="#">Link</a>
</nav>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RZQPPe